# Creating a transitive and not reflexive function in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm trying to create a function in Z3 that is transitive but not reflexive. I.e. if `(transitive a b)` and `(transitive b c)`hold then `(transitive a c)` should hold, but `(transitive a a)` should not.

I've tried to do it the following way, with 5 "tests". The first does what I expect, but the second one fails and results in `unknown`.

```
(declare-datatypes () ((T T1 T2 T3)))

(declare-fun f (T T) Bool)
(assert(f T1 T2))
(assert(f T2 T3))

; Make sure that f is not reflexive
(assert
  (forall ((x T))
    (not (f x x))))

; Now we create the transitivity function ourselves
(define-fun-rec transitive ((x T) (y T)) Bool
    (or 
        (f x y)
        (exists ((z T))
            (and 
                (f x z)
                (transitive z y)))))

; This works and gives sat
(push)
(assert (not (transitive T1 T1)))
(assert (not (transitive T2 T2)))
(assert (not (transitive T3 T3)))
(check-sat)
(pop)

; This fails with "unknown" and the verbose flag gives: (smt.mbqi "max instantiations 1000 reached")
(push)
(assert 
    (forall ((x T))
        (not (transitive x x))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

My question is: how does the second test differ from the first? Why does the last one give `unknown`, whereas the one before that works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "verbose" message is a hint here. `mbqi` stands for model-based-quantifier-instantiation. It's a method of dealing with quantifiers in SMT solving. In the first case, MBQI manages to find a model. But your `transitive` function is just too complicated for MBQI to handle, and thus it gives up. Increasing the limit will not likely address the problem, nor it's a long term solution.

Short story long, recursive definitions are difficult to deal with, and recursive definitions with quantifiers are even harder. The logic becomes semi-decidable, and you're at the mercy of heuristics. Even if you found a way to make z3 compute a model for this, it would be brittle. These sorts of problems are just not suitable for SMT solving; better use a proper theorem prover like Isabelle, Hol, Coq, Lean. Agda, etc. Almost all these tools offer "tactics" to dispatch subgoals to SMT solvers, so you have the best of both worlds. (Of course you lose full automation, but with quantifiers present, you can't expect any better.)